# How to use C# and VB.Net tags for questions containing no code and no language specific requirements

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19689664/838807) where the OP has used `VB.Net` as one of the tags. The question does not contain any code, and does not relate directly to VB.Net - The question is applicable to WPF and the .Net framework in general, but not specific to either `C#` or `VB.Net`.

There is (currently) only a single answer to the question, which has been accepted, and the code provided with that answer is in `C#`.

So the question is, has the `VB.Net` tag been correctly used here? If not, what action should be taken in regards to re-tagging?

If it is agreed that the question is specific only to `WPF` and `.Net` then should we remove the `VB.Net` tag to indicate that the language is not relevant? Or perhaps we should add the `C#` tag to indicate it is applicable to both?

On the flip side, is it a valid use of the tag because the OP might effectively be saying "I want answers in VB code"?

Comment: I would just remove the language tag, possibly adding a comment to explain what I did and why.

Comment: Hey, I don't know how to scroll this into view.  If it does require code, I am a VB.NET dev, not a C# dev, so I'd like to get code samples in that language if possible.  Thanks.

Comment: @Won't: Are you suggesting the OP should be clear if they want language specific answers? Or that using the tag is effectively saying that for them?

Comment: @musefan: The tag was clear enough to me.

Answer (score 1):

> Q:So the question is, has the VB.Net tag been correctly used here?

Yes and no. I can see why OP thought it was relevant when he posted the question and he might have been - but the fact a C# answer was accepted indicates it did not end up being the case.

People tend to tag the programming languages they use (Like JS for DOM API questions that work the same way in C#, or PHP or whatever). If [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) itself is no longer relevant or was never relevant **to the question** it should be removed.

I'd like to make a distinction between the question and the answers. The re-tagging is related to the question itself - it would be inappropriate to re-tag a "How do I iterate a sequence of numbers in C#" question with python or with language agnostic just because they got and accepted a Python answer.

> Tags are keywords or labels that categorize and group your question with other, similar questions.

At the end of the day that's the guideline - is it similar to other VB.NET questions? Is there a binding between it and VB.NET specifically?

> Q: If not, what action should be taken in regards to re-tagging?

Tagging it with [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) and [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) sounds like the appropriate course of action. The VB.NET tag is not relevant.

Comment: That said, if removing the tag is the *only* change, then that would be a bit too minimal. Having the VB.NET tag is not innappropriate nor does it do any real harm. I would not edit it out unless I was performing some other "enhancements" at the same time.

Comment: @JDB I agree, this is not a 'big' problem. Retagging is quick and fast though and does not require going into 'full edit mode'.

Comment: Yes, you don't need full edit mode, but, if I'm not mistaken, the question still gets bumped on the "Active" tab and the edit counts toward the "Wiki-fication" of the post.

Comment: Interesting arguments.

Answer (score -2):

This question doesn't include also any example of what the OP has tried. It also is asking for example, which is considered off-topic on SO:

> Questions asking us to **recommend** or find a tool, library or favorite
>   off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to
>   attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem
>   and what has been done so far to solve it.

Because even the target language is not specified, and the problem description is vague, it's a good candidate for **unclear what you're asking** as well.

Comment: I don't agree that this is a recommendation question, it is asking how to do something. I would have close voted it has we still got our reason of "lack of effort", but now that is gone, and despite what I have read on meta I still can't work out which reason should be used for question showing no effort to solve the problem, assuming we even care about that anymore

Comment: This question is *not* off-topic - it is about programming and doesn't tread into "off-topic" territory. It, at most, "does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." If you feel that is the case, use your downvote privelege, not your [super downvote](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/a-close-vote-is-not-a-super-downvote-please-dont-use-it-as-one) privelege.